# How to get respective modal on click of a link comes from loop using ng bootstrap in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have few li tags whose data comes from loop. There is also a link 'images', When you click it, it should open respective modal like For 'Cat' row cat image should come,For 'Architecture' row Architecture image should come,For 'baboon' row baboon image should come. For now only cat link is coming on click of 'image' link.you can use these link for particular image
Architecture - https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png
Baboon - https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png , Here is the code below with demo url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-327axj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div>
    <pre>

  </pre>
    <ul>
<li *ngFor="let item of statusdata" (click)="toggleActive(item, !item.active)">
  <span>{{item.id}}</span>&nbsp;
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>&nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Image</button>
</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">

    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <img style="width:100%" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" />
  </div>

</ng-template>



<hr>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

 statusdata: any;
closeResult: string;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.statusdata = [
      { id: 1, name: "Cat"},
      { id: 2, name: "Architecture"},
      { id: 3, name: "baboon" },


    ];

    this.statusdata.forEach(item => {
      this.getCacheItemStatus(item);
    });
  }

  toggleActive(item, activeStatus = true) {
    item.active = activeStatus;
    localStorage.setItem(`item:${item.id}`, JSON.stringify(item));
  }

  getCacheItemStatus(item) {
    const cachedItem = localStorage.getItem(`item:${item.id}`);
    if (cachedItem) {
      const parse = JSON.parse(cachedItem); // Parse cached version
      item.active = parse.active; // If the cached storage item is active
    }
  }

open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're hard coding the image url in the modal to use the cat image as follows:

```
<img style="width:100%" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" />
```

which causes the same image to be displayed in all modals.
You could maintain a variable for the image name and set it to the required image when you open the modal.
While calling the open method, pass the item name which will act as the image source:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content, item.name)">Image</button>
```

and handle it in the typescript class:

```
open(content, source) {
  this.imageSource = source;
...
```

where imageSource is just a variable:

```
imageSource: any;
```

And now the updated image URL will be:

```
<img style="width:100%" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/{{imageSource}}.png" />
```

Here is the updated stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bslf3q